# How to link user stories in Azure DevOps which can be tested together

Tags: azure-devops, devops, scrum, sprint, scrumboard

**Problem Statement**

I regularly have several user stories in a sprint. All stories have separate tasks for development and testing.

Usually these user stories are developed independently, but sometimes tested together. How can these relationships be represented in Azure DevOps?

**User Story**

*As* a user of Azure DevOps
*I want* to open the current sprint
*So that* I see the stories related to each other that are also to be tested together

**Workaround**

I assign separate tags to the user stories and have set up rules that change the colour of the user stories when assigning certain tags.

For example, three user stories have the tag testSetOne, so I created a rule that a user story is coloured red with this tag.

The manual managed, however, I want to bypass and hope, there is already a better solution anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a work item with the type Test Case.
[image]

Then, assign this work item to the related stories with the "Tested By" relationship.
[image]